# Is this black two-sided clip an original part made by LEGO?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Is this an original LEGO part? Maybe Technic? See the cup for size comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The black one is a playmobil part, used to link fort wall part together. I think the cup is playmobil too.

[image: Playmobil fort]

Comment: the playmobil origin is absolutely possible. i bought this in a used bulk on ebay. thanx for the answer. but now i wonder if playmobil stole the cup design or vice versa? ;-)

Comment: To see if the cup is genuine LEGO or not, look for the "LEGO" logo and the part ID hidden somewhere, like on the bottom, on the inside, on the end or the inside of the handle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recognize this part as produced by LEGO. On another thought, pictured black part has rough edges (low quality), which is unheard for LEGO.

Comment: yep, the quality argument makes totally sense